# InvokeComponent from inside If statement

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

If I invoke a ViewComponent outside of the scope of the if statement they both render just fine, but if I try to Invoke them inside the if statement then they produce no errors, just end up blank on the website.

What's causing them not to render inside the block?

_Layout Razer code:

```
     @if (ViewData["MenuName"] != null) {
         await Component.InvokeAsync("MensMenu");
     }
     else{
         await Component.InvokeAsync("DefaultMenu");
     }
```

Home Controller

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["MenuName"] = "HomeMenu";
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: I believe that's because you're ignoring the resulting task. Consider changing signature of `Index` to `public Task<IActionResult> Index()`

Comment: @orhtej2 I have the async task covered in the View Component controller `public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()`

Comment: I figured out the answer to this question and posted it below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code should be:

```
    @if (ViewData["MenuName"] != null) {
         @await Component.InvokeAsync("MensMenu");
     }
     else{
         @await Component.InvokeAsync("DefaultMenu");
     }
```

I forgot the @ before await.

Comment: Thank you! Had the exact same issue of the missing "@" before my `await` statement.